# How to combine results from multiple linq queries and then sort?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a method that takes in a search key and a page number and returns a page of data. (`GetDataPage` uses `Skip` and `Take` methods to get the right page.)

```
public JsonResult SearchResults(string searchKey, int page) {
   var data = dbContext.MyTable.Where(x => x.Title.Contains(searchKey)).OrderByDescending(x => x.CreatedDate);
   return GetDataPage(data, page);
}
```

This is working as expected.
Now I need to change the function so that it takes a list of searchKeys, search MyTable for all the search keys, order result and return the desired page. How do I combine the search results from multiple LINQ queries?

Comment: With Union? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386993(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Why multiple queries? Single query with proper `Where` should do it.

Comment: You current are searching for character in the string searchKey instead of string[] searchKey.  Your linq shouldn't need to change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this single LINQ query using [Any](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

```
public JsonResult SearchResults(IEnumerable<string> searchKeys, int page)
{
    var data = dbContext.MyTable.Where(x => searchKeys.Any(serachKey => x.Title.Contains(searchKey))).OrderByDescending(x => x.CreatedDate):
    return GetDataPage(data, page);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If for some reason you really need multiple queries you could do it like this:

```
searchKeys.SelectMany(key => dbContext.MyTable.Where(x => x.Title.Contains(searchKey)))
          .OrderByDescending(x => x.CreatedDate)
```